# Dúvida no <option> do <select>

Tags: php, html

Estou tentando utilizar a variável *SESSION* para passar valores para os campos, como foi utilizado no "login", onde se existir algo dentro da variável, será mostrado no campo, mas se não existir, não será mostrado nada. Como posso fazer o mesmo no *select*?

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="nome" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Login</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="login" placeholder="Login" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['login_consultar']; unset($_SESSION['login_consultar']);?>">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="nivel_acesso" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Nível de Acesso</label>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <select class="form-control" name="nivel_acesso">
            <option value="1">Administração</option>
            <option value="2">Informática</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: E como o amigo @FelipeDuarte respondeu. Da pra fazer assim, mas não se usa essa forma de fazer isso. Você deve gerar esse conteúdo e passar o valor com uma variável.

Comment: E como faço isso? Comecei a utilizar a linguagem faz pouco tempo.

Comment: Como você está definindo esta `$_session`? De onde vem o valor?

Comment: Estou utilizando dessa forma: $_SESSION['nivel_acesso_consultar'] = $resultado['nivel_acesso']; - Onde $resultado é uma _mysqli_fetch_assoc_ de uma consulta mysql

Comment: Porque ta passando para um session? porque não passa direto? Ta em outro arquivo a consulta?

Comment: Sim, está em outro arquivo.

Comment: Faça um `include` no meio desse arquivo. Ante de exibir este formulario, você faça o include.

Comment: Se exercite bastante na linguagem. Sempre que ver uma função nova e não conhece-la apreenda sobre ela. Após isso comece a programar encima de Frameworks. Vai ficar mais facil.

Comment: Vou fazer isso. Obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neste caso você precisa verificar o valor da variável para cada `option`, e caso seja o `option` seleciona, imprimir o atributo `selected` no option. Exemplo:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="nome" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Login</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="login" placeholder="Login" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['login_consultar']; unset($_SESSION['login_consultar']);?>">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="nivel_acesso" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Nível de Acesso</label>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <select class="form-control" name="nivel_acesso">
            <option value="1"<?php if($_SESSION['login_consultar'] == '1') { echo ' selected="selected"'; } ?>>Administração</option>
            <option value="2"<?php if($_SESSION['login_consultar'] == '2') { echo ' selected="selected"'; } ?>>Informática</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Dessa forma

```
<?php if(isset($_SESSION['teste'])) : ?>
    <option value="<?= $_SESSION['teste'] ?>"> teste </option>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Porém se estiver usando `sessions` somente para passar valores referente ao conteúdo, é melhor rever sua lógica.

Comment: O que você me recomenda, então? Comecei a trabalhar com a linguagem faz pouco tempo.

Comment: Para passar valores pelas páginas use $_POST ou $_GET, mediante a um formulário, se necessita recuperar dados,entre as páginas, já entra na questão de banco de dados, a superglobal $_SESSION é para controle de sessão exemplo verificar se um usuário foi setado ou não, e a mesma tem de ser destruída.